# Show div only when the mouse hovers over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

**My question is what would be the preferred code to accomplish the reblog and like button, only showing when I hover over a post?** as should here: http://giraffes-cant-dance.tumblr.com/

I'm working on a personal website, at [www.onwardandbeyond.tumblr.com](http://www.onwardandbeyond.tumblr.com) and the posts are going horzontally across the page, instead of up and down.

I also wanted to create a website where when you hover over a post the following show: reblog button, like button, permalink and the information about who the source who originally created the post is.

Is there an easier way for this to be achieved that actually works because nothing I seem to come up with does.

HTML:

```
<div id="date">
    {block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}"> {DayOfWeek} {ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero}, {Year}, >{TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}
    {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}
</div>

<div id="info">
    {block:RebloggedFrom}
    reblog: <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentTitle}">
        {ReblogParentName} 
    </a>
    origin: <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">
        {ReblogRootName}>
    <a/>
    {/block:RebloggedFrom}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#info {
    color:#000;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font: 10px Consolas;
}
#info {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:;
    margin-left:;
}
#info {
    padding-top: 620px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:280px;
}
#info a {
    color: #000;
}
#date a, {
    width: 280px;
    color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    visibility: visible:
}
#date {
    display: none;
}
#date:hover #date {
    display : block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please edit your post, such that it includes an actual question (rather than an implied one). As it stands, your intentions are unclear.

Comment: If you've not seen it, this may help: http://tumblring.net/tumblr-reblog-button/ (I don't use tumblr, sorry if it's unhelpful and a waste of time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the things you want to show up within the div you want to hover. If the wrapper div is `.wrapper` and the hover items are in a div `.controls`:

```
.controls {
    display:none;
}

.wrapper:hover .controls {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing how this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/6Fq5E/

If the two are siblings (and the controls can't be within the wrapper), then you can use the following:

```
.div:hover ~ .controls {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for this version. http://jsfiddle.net/UxxKr/1/

Comment: That isn't working for me, I'm sure that I must be missing something within my code.

Comment: I updated the post with jsfiddles showing how each works. You need to adapt this to your code (based on your HTML). I still don't understand from your post what you want hovered and what you want to show (based on the HTML). If you can say I want `#div` hovered and show `#span`, then we can give you exact CSS

Comment: WOAH! Thank you! It's working. I started over and began with your tips. Now all I have to do is start reapplying the styles, and hope everything sticks. Thanks again, for the update. You Superman'd this project for me. (please feel free to supplement hero you actually life)

Comment: Sure. Keep in mind that you can replace the `display` switching with other methods, too. With `opacity:0;` to `opacity:1;` for example, to which you can apply a CSS transition to make it look quite smooth. Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity) for browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

css

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

html

```
<a>Hover</a>
<div>This to show on hover</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that. I'm nore sure why it didn't show. My current one shows:#date{ 
display: none;
}
#date:hover #datw{
display : block;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
#date:hover+#info,#info:hover{display:block}
```